# Whats the difference between `type a = { someType:someType }` and `type a = A(someType)`

Tags: reason, bucklescript

Like for simple team and game types

```
type team =
  | Team(string);

type game1 =
  | Game(team, team);

type game2 = {
  team1: team,
  team2: team,
};
```

1. What is the difference between `game1` and `game2`?
2. In real world when to declare `type game` like `game1` or when to declare like `game2`?
3. Are there any other ways this thing can be defined in Reason?

Comment: This is the kind of question that documentation, books and tutorials answer. It is too broad for Stack Overflow. See [ask] and the [help/on-topic]. [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/) is a good book, available online.

Comment: `game1` is called a "variant", or in type theory a "sum type". `game2` is a "record", or "product type". Look up [Algebraic Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) for a more general theoretic explanation of the differences between sum types and product types.

Comment: Variant can be useful for pattern matching. Since there is only one possible `Game(team,team)` so whats the difference between `Game` and `game2`. Any link will also be helpful.

Comment: `Game` is a type constructor.  In order to make a `game1`, you have to use one of its constructors- in this case you only have one.  I particularly like these for modeling view state `type viewState = | Loaded(user) | Loading | Failed(string);`

Comment: agree with @glennsl, but since Game from game1 has a payload (team, team) which somewhat like game2 without names for the two teams) it holds a product type, and since you have only one variant, i think its sematically the same. In this case i would go for game2, because you don't need to handle a single case all the time